# Why does NULL fail when calling the API by ManualMapping winhttp.dll?

Tags: loadlibrary, winhttp

I am a win10 user and wanted to use winhttp.dll as manualloadlibrary on memory to be free from API Hook.

All dlls in the import table and delay import table of manually mapped winhttp.dll were loaded and even dllmain was called, but when the WinHttpOpen function is called, NULL is always returned and the GetLastError value is 0x7E.

When calling WinHttpOpen without ManualMapping with the same arguments, it succeeds normally.

What am I missing? Can't I use winhttp.dll by ManualMapping?